# Especially: emphasis or exclusion?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does the word especially exclude and discount anything that is not denoted?

For instance in the following example, would this sentence mean only those in Florida, or is it simply an emphasis and those outside of Florida could also be included.

> People love desserts, especially those in Florida.

Comment: It definitely refers to those who live/are in Florida.

Comment: So youre saying, this sentence says only those in Florida love desserts, no one else?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't refer to desserts in Florida?

Comment: No, please look up “especially” in a dictionary.

Comment: @JohnLawler the context is irrelevant to the answer im looking for, i just want to know if the word especially is used for emphasis or exclusion

Comment: @user66974 i did and the usage was nebulous to me, and now im here. So youre saying its used as emphasis, not exclusion?

Comment: @JohnLawler - is Florida renowned  for desserts?

Comment: Indeed. Key lime pie comes to mind. But most of America is renowned for desserts. _Especially_, by the way, is strictly emphasis. Using it for exclusion occurs, but you need to add just the right intonation and facial expression to get it across. In print that's impossible.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. It is not clear if **those** refers to **people** or **desserts in Florida**.  Arguably based on word order it means **desserts in Florida**.

Comment: @JohnLawler - well, if I think about Florida, a dessert  is the last thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @FeliniusRex it was intentionally ambiguous because i didnt want people to focus on the context, and instead focus on my question. Mission failed

Comment: If you make something ambiguous, you **force** people to consider context. How else can they resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: I don’t think that ambiguity of those (people or desserts) has any implication on the “emphasis or exclusion” issue. Especially = emphasis, Except =exclusion.

Comment: All people love dessert. Some love it more than others. No one is excluded. All desserts are loved. Some are loved more than others. No dessert is excluded. Use *specifically* to exclude: *People love desserts, specifically those [desserts] in Florida. People—specifically those in Florida—love desserts.*

Comment: Why do you think “especially” is exclusive? Is there a definition you’ve found that suggests that?

Comment: @Xanne i think its its emphatic not exclusive but the definition is nebulous and was recently a topic of debate i encountered

Comment: @polar, perhaps it might be useful if you summarise what arguments were presented on the other side of that debate; that would help to show that there is a genuine question here. It may also be helpful if you explain what is it that you found 'nebulous' about the dictionary definitions of the term.